# Hide Soft Keyboard using adb

Tags: android, shell, adb, android-softkeyboard

I want to hide soft keyboard using adb shell command. Is there any specific command available to do so or in any ways can I get the current focus window object over adb on which I can hide the keyboard if showing?

Answer (score 12):

you can hide your keyboard with

```
adb shell input keyevent 111
```

you can find all keyevents are here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html

Answer (score 2):

@Matthias Miro answer is 4.5 years old and it did not work for me with Android 9.
Instead I found the following solution [in a GitHub issue thread](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy/issues/181) which worked:

1. Install [Null Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wparam.nullkeyboard)
2. Select it via ADB: `adb shell ime set com.wparam.nullkeyboard/.NullKeyboard`

to get your original keyboard back:

1. List all available keyboards: `adb shell ime list -s -a`
2. Select the one via: `adb shell ime set [keyboard line from previous command]`

Answer (score 2):

you can hide your keyboard by just send the back keyevent

```
adb shell input keyevent 4 # KEYCODE_BACK
```

Keyevents reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html

Comment: Much more reasonable than the other answers here

Answer (score 1):

I have found a faster and easier solution through adb, by disabling the keyboard entirely.

you can hide your keyboard permament with

```
adb shell pm disable-user com.android.inputmethod.latin
```

Answer (score 0):

Otherwise disable only 1 time (equivalent to hide_keyboard in Appium test automation)

```
adb shell ime reset
```

Explanation:

```
$ adb shell ime -h

ime <command>:
  list [-a] [-s]
    prints all enabled input methods.
      -a: see all input methods
      -s: only a single summary line of each
  enable [--user <USER_ID>] <ID>
    allows the given input method ID to be used.
      --user <USER_ID>: Specify which user to enable. Assumes the current user if not specified.
  disable [--user <USER_ID>] <ID>
    disallows the given input method ID to be used.
      --user <USER_ID>: Specify which user to disable. Assumes the current user if not specified.
  set [--user <USER_ID>] <ID>
    switches to the given input method ID.
      --user <USER_ID>: Specify which user to enable. Assumes the current user if not specified.
  reset [--user <USER_ID>]
    reset currently selected/enabled IMEs to the default ones as if the device is initially booted w
    ith the current locale.
      --user <USER_ID>: Specify which user to reset. Assumes the current user if not specified.
```

Otherwise:

- Get the current active keyboard:  `adb shell "ime list -s"`
- Disable permanently the current keyboard:  `adb shell "ime disable {IME_KEYBOARD_VALUE}"`
- Later on, restore the keyboard:  `adb shell "ime reset"`